Decoupling networking management with the processing of generating messages to be sent which may need some calculation
The code snippet below is used to read/write tcp message. And the messages are sent(i.e. the void Conversation::do_write(std::string content)) by other threads which is not the one ever called io_context.run() in practice.
//Godbolt does not have standalone asio, I do not want to use boos::asio since it's huge.
#include "boost/asio.hpp" 
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <array>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

using namespace boost;
using asio::ip::tcp;

class TcpServer
{
public:
  TcpServer(asio::io_context& io_context,
      const unsigned int& port);

private:
  void do_accept();

  tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
};

class Conversation : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Conversation>
{
public:
  Conversation(tcp::socket socket);
  virtual ~Conversation();
  void do_start();
  void do_read();
  void do_write(std::string content);
private:
  tcp::socket m_socket;
  std::array<char, 1024*2> m_data;

  //UPDATE1: make the write buffers as member variables.
  std::mutex m_mutex;   // to protect m_write_queue
  std::list<std::string> m_write_queue; //messages to be sent to client
};

TcpServer::TcpServer(asio::io_context& io_context,
      const unsigned int& port):m_acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
{
  do_accept();
}

void TcpServer::do_accept()
{
      m_acceptor.async_accept(make_strand(m_acceptor.get_executor()),
      [this](const std::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket)
      {
            if (!error)
            {
              std::make_shared<Conversation>(std::move(socket))->do_start();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "Error accepting connection: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            }

            // Start accepting the next connection
            do_accept();
      });
}

Conversation::Conversation(tcp::socket socket) : m_socket(std::move(socket))
{ 
  std::cout << "creating conversation:" << this << std::endl;
}

void Conversation::do_read()
{
    std::cout << "do read" << std::endl;
    auto conversation_ptr(shared_from_this());
     m_socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(m_data),
        [this, conversation_ptr](std::error_code error, size_t length) {
          if (!error)
          {
              do_write(std::string("reply:") + std::string{m_data.data(), length});
              do_read();
              std::cout << "data read: " << std::string(m_data.data(), length) << std::endl;
          }
          else
          {
              std::cout << "error in reading data: " << error.message() << std::endl;
          }
        });
}

void Conversation::do_start()
{
  do_read();
}


void Conversation::do_write(std::string content)
{
  auto conversation_ptr(shared_from_this());
  auto buffer_ptr = &content[0];
  auto buffer_size = content.size();
  std::string to_send_str;
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_write_queue.push_back(std::move(content));
    std::cout << "queue size(): " << m_write_queue.size() << std::endl;
  }

  //UPDATE1: make the write buffers as member variables.
  //Why not use m_write_queue.back() directly? Because m_write_queue may be pushed new data into it by other threads at the same time.
  m_socket.async_send(asio::const_buffer(buffer_ptr, buffer_size), [this, conversation_ptr](std::error_code error, size_t length ){
    if (!error)
    {
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_write_queue.pop_front();
      }
      std::cout << "data write successfully" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error in writing data: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  });
}

Conversation::~Conversation()
{
   std::cout << "destroying conversation:" << this << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  asio::io_context io_context;
  TcpServer server{io_context, 12345};

  io_context.run();
}


Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the purpose of the code, rather than its mechanism.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  It's best to describe what value this code provides to its user.
